# Pause and Resume SKScene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2, xcode7

I was testing my game on my iPhone and I realized that I have a problem with the home button. When I pause the game and load another app the game is not paused and continues when the app is not on screen.

Here's the code:

```
 class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate{

 var PauseButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "pause")

 var Resume = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "resume1")
}


 init(size: CGSize, won: Bool) {
    super.init(size: size)      
  //pause

    PauseButton.position = CGPointMake(330, 700)
    PauseButton.zPosition = 3;
    PauseButton.size = CGSizeMake(40, 40);
    PauseButton.name = "PauseButton"

    self.addChild(PauseButton)

   //resume 
    Resume = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "resume1")
    Resume.position = CGPointMake(520, 450)
    Resume.zPosition = 100
    Resume.setScale(1.3)   

    }

 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    show = self.scene as SKScene!


    for touch in touches  {


        let Location:CGPoint = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let Node:SKNode = self.nodeAtPoint(Location)



        if(Node == PauseButton){


            self.show.paused = true

            PauseButton.removeFromParent()

            self.addChild(Resume)

        }

        if(Node == Resume){


            Resume.removeFromParent()
            self.show.paused = false

            self.addChild(PauseButton)
        }
```

How do I get the game to pause when I press the home button?

Answer (score 2):

Pause the view not the scene.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let view = view else {
        return
    }

    view.paused = !view.paused
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SpriteKit will auto Resume when you comeback to your app. so you need :

Step 1 : create a variable :

```
var wasPaused : Bool = false
```

Step 2 : change it in your pause/resume function :

```
wasPaused = true // pause func
wasPaused = false // resume fun
```

Step 3 : in update fun of your scene:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    if isPausing{
        self.paused = true
        return
    }
}
```